# Pandas histogram with 2 columns and known frequencies

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, histogram

I have a dataframe df that looks like this:

```
    INDEX     VAL
0        1  23.0
1   250001  23.0
2   500001  23.0
3   750001  18.0
4  1000001   0.0
```

How can I plot a histogram where the x-axis has the index and y is the value of VAL, and the histogram bars are 1-250001, 250001-500001, etc?

So for example, from 1-250001 the bar should be at height 23.

Comment: What have you tried? I guess, using matplotlib would be the default approach...

Comment: It sounds like you want a bar plot, not a histogram.  A histogram is generally visualized as a bar plot with the _number of data points_ in a bin as the height of the bar.

Comment: @Ben G. Yes indeed. I would like the value 23 to represent the number of data points between 1 and 250001. So I would like a histogram to represent that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have the frequency, what you need is a bar plot; You can adjust the *plot* parameters to make it look like a histogram:

```
import matplotlib
%matplotlib inline
ax = df.set_index('INDEX').plot(kind="bar", color="#dd55ff", position=0, width=1.0, rot=0)
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I need! This is fantastic thank you! I just did not know how to manipulate the bar plot to do that.